# How to save the extracted Contours in a separate data type

Tags: java, android, opencv, contour

I am new to `openCV` and therefore I have a few problems.

My code so far looks like this:

```
List<MatOfPoint> contours = mDetector.getContours();
Imgproc.drawContours(mRgba, contours, -1, CONTOUR_COLOR);
```

This code draws the extracted contours. 
I want to save all the points on which contours is drawn in an `array`.
My image size is `480*800`.